# Creating a Change Log using VBA Insert Into

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a change log anytime a field is changed. I want it to record the property, the manager, and the date it was changed. I looked up INSERT INTO and followed the directions and came up with this code, but I get an error.

```
Private Sub Manager_AfterUpdate()

INSERT INTO tbl_ManagerChangeLog (Property, NewMan, [Date Change])
    VALUES (Me.ID, Me.Manager, DATE())

End Sub
```

There error I get reads, "Compile Error: Expected: End of statement"

Any help is appreciated.

Here is final code that worked for me. Thank you for all of the help.
    Private Sub Manager_Change()

```
Dim dbs As Database, PropID As Integer, ManNam As String, ChangeDate As Date

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    PropID = Me.ID
    ManNam = Me.Manager
    ChangeDate = Date

    dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_ManagerChangeLog " & "(Property, NewMan, DateChange)VALUES " & "(" & PropID & ", " & ManNam & ", #" & ChangeDate & "#);"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following VBA to run a sql query.

```
Private Sub Manager_AfterUpdate()

Dim strSql As String , Db As dao.Database 

strSql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ManagerChangeLog (Property, NewMan, [Date Change]) VALUES (Me.ID, Me.Manager, DATE());" 

'Use Current Database 
Set Db = CurrentDb() 

'Run the SQL Query 
Db.Execute strSql 

End Sub
```

Comment: `Me.ID` and `Me.Manager` are meaningful on the form, but the db engine doesn't know anything about them.  Use their *values* in the `INSERT` statement or create a parameter query and supply their values as parameters.

Comment: When I ran this code, it said too few parameters expected 2. Could that be because an autonumber primary key must also be added? Or does it mean that HansUp is right?

Answer (score 1):

You must run a SQL query using Execute funcion from currentDb object, and build the query values concatenating values:

```
Private Sub Manager_AfterUpdate()
   Dim sSQL as String
   sSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_ManagerChangeLog (Property, NewMan, [Date Change]) " & _
          "VALUES (" & Me.ID & ",'" & Me.Manager "'," & _ 
                    "#" & format(DATE(),"YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS") & "#)"

   currentDB.Execute sSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: When I put in your code, I got the same error I was before and it highlights the "',#" after Me.Manager

Comment: It must be properly formatted, I change my answer and add the format function to date field.